# node.js with mkdir/mkdirp and setuid

Tags: node.js, mkdir

i am trying to use node.js mkdirp to create a directory in another users area.

in other words, i have user foo and bar.  i wish to have mkdirp run as user foo but create a directory in bars area.

from a previous SO post, and much experimenting, it appears this cannot be done.  i have tried putting both bar into foo's group via *usermod*, putting foo into bar's group, and played extensively with *setfacl* as well.

this is a bit odd to me, considering i am able to **su foo;** and create a directory, touch, delete, etc. in bar's directory.

i have even tried using the regular fs.mkdir command and that has the same issue (probably no surprise there) - the code is below.

when the node program first starts, i downgrade the running privilege using setuid/setgid from user 'root' to user 'foo'.

my question:  is it possible to somehow retain the root privilege but restrict the root privilege long enough just to run the mkdirp command and nothing else?

thank you all for your time and consideration.  my experimental code is below:

```
fs = require('fs') ;
process.setgid(556);  // foos groupid
process.setuid(560);  // foos userid

fs.mkdir('/test1/test2/testTester/', 0770, function(err){
   if (err) console.error(err)   else console.log('works!');
});
```

> **id foo;**
>
> uid=560(foo) gid=556(foo) groups=556(foo),512(bar)
>
> **id bar;**
>
> uid=515(bar) gid=512(bar) groups=512(bar)

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaround solution (for now) - use visudo and grant user foo mkdir privileges:

**visudo ;**    ## include the following line:

> foo ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /bin/mkdir,/bin/chown

and here is my working node.js test script:

```
exec = require('exec');

process.setgid(556);  // foo's groupid
process.setuid(560);  // foo's userid

exec('sudo /bin/mkdir --parents /test1/test2/testTester/; ', function(error,stdout,stderr){
    if (error == '' ) {     // null does not work here for some reason
        exec('sudo /bin/chown bar:bar  /test1/test2/testTester/; ', function(error,stdout,stderr){
            if (error != '' ) {
                 console.log('chown exec error: ' + error);       
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('mkdir exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

as always, any comments are very welcome and appreciated.